# Chrome Debugger how to inspect elements of the dropdown menu

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, html

For the dropdown menu on one of my webpage, after I click to do Inspect element on one of menu items, the dropdown menu would collapse and disappear, and such that I couldn't check the content of the dropdown menu in the html and neither really check the corresponding css styles (and further play with the styles). Is there a way to freeze the dropdown menu after clicking to do the Inspect element operation?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Have you been able to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

After clicking on the menu, press F8 to pause script execution. That should keep your menu open so you can inspect it.

Comment: Wanted to add this doesn't work every time but after a few tries the dropdown remained open.